# Знак препинания

Tags: запятая

Здравствуйте! Подскажите, пожалуйста, как верно написать.
1)Нет, он не глупый, скорее - невнимательный.
2)Нет, он не глупый, скорее, невнимательный.
3)Нет, он не глупый, скорее невнимательный.

Answer (score 5):

Слово *скорее* в данном примере не является  вводным, оно не уточняет сказанное ранее,  а усиливает противопоставление. Поэтому запятая после "скорее" не нужна. Тире возможно как интонационное.

Answer (score 1):

1-й и 3-й варианты возможны выбор зависит от вкладываемого автора оттенка смысла. 
В нейтральном варианте я написал бы по первому варианту. Третий вариант - если автор хочет немного скрыть явное противопоставление глупый-невнимательный.

Что касается второго варианта, то он очень сомнительный. "Скорее" в принципе может играть роль вводного слова, но тут для такой трактовки нет никаких оснований.

Comment: Спасибо. Изначально я склонялась к первому варианту. Но что-то ни в одном словаре не нашла подобного написания. Может не там искала, но... меня удивило отсутствие подобных примеров.

Comment: Вы искали знаки препинания в словарях?

Comment: behemothus, многие, говоря словарь, имеют в виду справочник.